# Errors when trying to ng build my Angular2 app

Tags: angular

I built an app for an Angular2 course that was made a couple years ago. The app works fine on my Localhost, but when I use ng build to create a dist folder in order to publish live on the internet, I am getting errors. Here is my package.json file:

```
{
    "name": "task-card-app",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "udemy.com Angular2 app built on skeleton project",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
        "lite": "lite-server",
        "tsc": "tsc",
        "tsc:w": "tsc -w"
    },
    "license": "UNLICENSED",
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": ""
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "^2.1.2",
        "@angular/compiler": "^2.1.2",
        "@angular/core": "^2.1.2",
        "@angular/forms": "^2.1.2",
        "@angular/http": "^2.1.2",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.1.2",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.1.2",
        "@angular/router": "3.1.2",
        "@angular/upgrade": "^2.1.2",
        "angular-in-memory-web-api": "0.1.13",
        "bootstrap": "4.0.0-alpha.5",
        "core-js": "2.4.1",
        "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
        "reflect-metadata": "0.1.8",
        "rxjs": "^5.0.0-beta.12",
        "systemjs": "0.19.40",
        "zone.js": "^0.6.25"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular/cli": "^1.7.4",
        "@types/core-js": "0.9.34",
        "@types/node": "6.0.46",
        "concurrently": "3.1.0",
        "lite-server": "2.2.2",
        "typescript": "2.0.6"
    }
}
```

With this configuration, ng build produced this message:

```
Your global Angular CLI version (6.0.1) is greater than your local
version (1.7.4). The local Angular CLI version is used.

This version of CLI is only compatible with angular version 2.3.1 or better. Please upgrade your angular version, e.g. by running:
npm install @angular/core@latest
```

Updating angular core produced many peer dependency issues and the following message:

```
Versions of @angular/compiler-cli and typescript could not be determined.
The most common reason for this is a broken npm install.
    Please make sure your package.json contains both @angular/compiler-cli and typescript in
    devDependencies, then delete node_modules and package-lock.json (if you have one) and
    run npm install again.
```

. . . and attempting to run it on localhost again I got a long list of node modules errors.

I added @angular/compiler-cli to devDependencies, and deleted package-lock.json and node_modules, then running ng build again produced this message:

```
Unable to find any apps in `.angular-cli.json`.
```

In other cases tinkering with the versions of things and running npm install and ng build produced:

```
Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found.
Error: Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found.
    at WorkspaceLoader._getProjectWorkspaceFilePath (C:\Users\cadle\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\workspace-loader.js:37:19)
    at WorkspaceLoader.loadWorkspace (C:\Users\cadle\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\workspace-loader.js:24:21)
    at BuildCommand._loadWorkspaceAndArchitect (C:\Users\cadle\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js:180:32)
    at BuildCommand.<anonymous> (C:\Users\cadle\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js:47:25)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\cadle\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js:7:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (C:\Users\cadle\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js:3:12)
    at BuildCommand.initialize (C:\Users\cadle\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js:46:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\cadle\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js:87:23)
```

I've been searching for hours and tried a few other things as well, but this is the gist of it.

My question is, how can I build my app into the dist folder so I can host the app on the internet?

**Update:**
I ran npm install on the original skeleton project that the above project was build on to find out if the problem was there from the beginning, and running ng build produced the same result as the on above which begins:

```
Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found.
```

As you can see in the package.json file below, devDependencies doesn't include "@angular/cli": "^1.7.4", but ng build still doesn't work. And if as mentioned in the comments below, 'angular.json' is Angular 6, I don't understand why it is being required to build an old Angular 2 skeleton project. Maybe it's because I'm running Angular 6 globally. I'll look into reverting to an older version globally and see if that makes a difference.

**Update:**
Nope. Installing an older version globally didn't help at all.

```
{
    "name": "angular2-skeleton",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "First Angular2 Skeleton Project",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
        "lite": "lite-server",
        "tsc": "tsc",
        "tsc:w": "tsc -w"
    },
    "license": "UNLICENSED",
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": ""
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "2.1.2",
        "@angular/compiler": "2.1.2",
        "@angular/core": "2.1.2",
        "@angular/forms": "2.1.2",
        "@angular/http": "2.1.2",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "2.1.2",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.1.2",
        "@angular/router": "3.1.2",
        "angular-in-memory-web-api": "0.1.13",
        "bootstrap": "4.0.0-alpha.5",
        "core-js": "2.4.1",
        "reflect-metadata": "0.1.8",
        "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
        "systemjs": "0.19.40",
        "zone.js": "0.6.26"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/core-js": "0.9.34",
        "@types/node": "6.0.46",
        "concurrently": "3.1.0",
        "lite-server": "2.2.2",
        "typescript": "2.0.6"
    }
}
```

Comment: `angular.json` is for Angular6 and `.angular-cli.json` was for Angular2-5

Comment: So it seems when you ran the `npm install` command on your old project it pulled in the later versions. I would say try removing all the `^`, delete the `node_modules` folder and re-run `npm install`.

Comment: Also, I don't believe Angular-CLI was around a couple of years ago, so pulling that from your `package.json` and building the app way you did back then. Or you are going to be forced to upgrade your app completely.

Comment: To  Andrew Lobban : For the record, my package.json originally didn't have the carrots, but I removed them again and tried your suggestion. ng build still produces the request to install install @angular/core@latest.

Comment: Also, the course was produced a couple years ago, but I only built the app recently. I don't know how I ended up with the "@angular/cli": "^1.7.4" in devDependencies, but the app doesn't run without it. I should add though that the app does contain a widget that was not built on the original course skeleton. I may have used the CLI for that. Not sure what effect that is having.